# Android Studio Manifest - intent filter problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Since I want to start my app with some animations. I need to start animation activity first. SplashActivity is animation activity.

In manifest I tried this:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.numberguessingapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NumberGuessingApp" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.numberguessingapp.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true" /> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name="com.company.numberguessingapp.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I got this error:

> A failure occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/kalilux/AndroidStudioProjects/NumberGuessingApp/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:25:
> AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

Line 25 is where  is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the all of the Manifest code. There's actaully a mistake in closing a tag of an activity with `intent-filter`

You should type

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.numberguessingapp.SplashActivity"
    android:exported="true"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

instead of

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.numberguessingapp.SplashActivity"
    android:exported="true" /> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: If I do that and build code, that </activity> removes. And android:exported = "true" /> comes back.

Comment: Then try removing `exported` tag from `MainActivity`.

Comment: It also come back when I rebuild project. I will have to make a new project. :(

Comment: Have you `cleaned` the project? If yes, then you tried `invalidate cache & restart`?

Comment: Yes. I'm using m1 macbook air, maybe that is a problem.

Comment: try removing these lines
`android:testOnly="true"` and 
`android:debuggable="true"`

Comment: The problem was the incorrect brackets. But if it doesn't work, then you have no option but to create a new project.

Comment: Nothing, I'll try later to rebuild it again. If it doesn't work I'll post comment here or answer. It depends :)

Comment: hmm..Good luck. :)

Comment: Yes, it was something with brackets.